# Record clicks in certain timeframe using javascript on html video

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video

the purpose of the script is for the user to click on the video on a certain timeframe for example, if something on the video prompts them to click at 11 seconds, they would have from 10.3 to 12 seconds to click to receive a point. They receive no point if they click outside this region. At the end of the video they would then receive a score. I also a start button too to start the video. This is the code so far:

```html
<video controls autoplay video id="test"
   width="800" height="600" name="Video Name" src="test.mov"></video>
 <video> <source src="test.ogg" type="video/ogg">
  Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>
```

```js
<script>
var vid = document.getElementById("test"); 
vid.onclick = testHazard;
var hazards, penalties;

hazards = [
  {
    start: 11.2,
    stop: 12.3,
    passed: false
  },
  {
    start: 27.1,
    stop: 29.0,
    passed: false
  },
  {
    start: 37.2,
    stop: 38.6,
    passed: false
  }
];

penalties = 0;

function testHazard(time) {
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < hazards.length; i++) {
    if (time >= hazards[i].start && time <= hazards[i].stop) {
      hazards[i].passed = true;
      return;
    }
  }
  penalties++;
}

function countPoints() {
  var i, points = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < hazards.length; i++) {
    if (hazards[i].passed) {
      points++;
    }
  }
  return (points - penalties);
}

// 3 clicks for the same hazard:
testHazard(1);
testHazard(1.1);
testHazard(1.2);

// 1 penalty click for no hazard:
testHazard(3);

// 1 click for 3rd hazard
testHazard(9);

alert("Total points: " + countPoints() +
      ", penalty points: " + penalties);

</script>
```

Could someone please inform me of where I'm going wrong? I receive the javascript alert as soon as the page loads,once I clicked ok on the alert,  the videos plays with which seems to be no response to the clicks. Thanks.

Comment: What is the javascript alert you are getting?

Comment: @EhsanT "Total Points: -5 Penalties: 5"

Comment: So the alert is showing the correct results, the reason that clicking on the video is not functioning I think is that it's interfering with the browser's native controls for pause and play. so you have co override the controls which I assume you can not. so the solution you have is to create an overlay `div` over the video and bind your `onclick` event to that `div`. also you have to pass the video current time to the function using `video.currentTime` property.